# Too many SQL Server users

Tags: sql-server, r, sql-server-2016, user-accounts

We have a VM with a SQL Server running. Today I wanted to add a user to the box and I noticed that there are 20 SQL Server windows users. I have no idea where these came from. The description says `Local user account for execution of R scripts in SQL Server instance MSSQLSERVER`

Anyone know what's up with these accounts that seem to appear out of nowhere?  What happens if I delete them?

[image]

Comment: Someone is forgetting to close a connection maybe?

Comment: @thelatemail Thanks looking into that.  I use C# with EF and always `using` block.  But to me, these appear to me different window users.  I'm also going to reboot the box to see what happens.

Comment: This has nothing to do with connections. These are local users. Someone created them. Check the Security Event Log. Do you have a script that creates such accounts? A stuck SQL Server Agent job that keeps retrying?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're running SQL Server 2016 with R Services enabled. These accounts are created as part of installation, and are used to run R processes when called from SQL.

From the [MSDN documentation:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt696069.aspx)

> **Step 3: Enable Implied Authentication for Launchpad Accounts**
>
> During setup, 20 new Windows user accounts are created for the purpose of running tasks under the security token of the SQL Server Trusted Launchpad service. When a user sends an R script from an external client, SQL Server will activate an available worker account, map it to the identity of the calling user, and run the R script on behalf of the user. This is a new service of the database engine that supports secure execution of external scripts, called implied authentication.
>
> You can view these accounts in the Windows user group, SQLRUserGroup. If you need to run R scripts from a remote data science client and are using Windows authentication, these worker accounts must be given permission to log into the SQL Server instance on your behalf.

Comment: Thanks Hong.  Good info!